# How can i install/configure or set up tomcat 7 manually?

Tags: eclipse, debian, tomcat7

I downloaded apache-tomcat-7.0.20.tar.gz from here => http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

Now how can i install/configure it manually to run springframework project with eclipse?

Comment: Just extract the file into some folder and reference it in *Servers* view of Eclipse. What exactly is your problem? Extracting the file? Referencing it in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm on debian , can i use tomcat-7 on debian ? no problem with extracting, how can i reference it in eclipse?

Comment: Tomcat is written in pure Java. You should be able to run it on every platform which has a JRE/JDK installed (you apparently has, otherwise you wouldn't be able to run Eclipse which is written in pure Java as well). Referencing goes usually by *Servers* view. Just rightclick, new, etc.

Comment: I code on Debian, so I can tell you that it will work great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to register your Tomcat server in Eclipse (`Window -> Preferences` and then select `Server -> Runtime Environments`). After this you will be able to deploy your projects directly from Eclipse.

Comment: Afterwards you create your web application and when you want to run your project, select "Run-> Run on server" and choose your Tomcat server. Have fun coding ;)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to install Tomcat. Just unpack it and start with the `startap.sh` or (`startup.bat` on windows) which is in the `bin` directory.

Also you can install it as a windows service or unix daemon, refer to the docs: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html

Comment: I'm on debian , can i use tomcat-7 on debian ?

Comment: Yes, Tomcat is Java application. If you have Java installed, then you can use Tomcat on Debian.

Comment: On Debian you may also have to go to [tomcat]/bin directory and run chmod +x *.sh to make all .sh scripts runnable.